# Django read 3 variables at once from list

Tags: python, django, list

I have the following List:

```
List (user1,user2,user3,user4,user5, user...n)
```

I need to show it like the following image:

[image]

I don't know how to to take 3 users from list on each iteration to force to each row to has 3 users.

Something like the following:

```
{% for user,user2,user3 in user_list %}
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-4">
      <form> <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-md btn-block" formaction="{% url 'interface:data' user.id %}">{{user.id}}</button> </form>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <form> <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-md btn-block" formaction="{% url 'interface:data' user2.id %}">{{user2.id}}</button> </form>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
        <form> <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-md btn-block" formaction="{% url 'interface:data' user3.id %}">{{user3.id}}</button> </form>
   </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845227/django-templates-group-items-in-threes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django templates: Group items in Threes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845227/django-templates-group-items-in-threes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django, templates, for loops, and cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679411/django-templates-for-loops-and-cycles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django templates let you check 'where you are' in the for loop, so all you have to do is open and close your rows appropriately:

```
{% for user in user_list %}
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"3" %}<div class="row">{% endif %}
   <div class="col align-self-center">
      <form> <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block" formaction="{% url 'interface:data' user.id %}">{{user.id}}</button> </form>
{% if forloop.last or forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}</div>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I want to generate a table from that user_list. I want 3 columns on each row.

Comment: But why do you want 3 columns - is `3` special because you have 3 users? Where is the `3` coming from?

Comment: It's just interface design, I want on each row 3 users.

Comment: OK, I understand. Check out the links that other users commented on your main post, as I think that's what you're looking for, and I'll try to update my answer to help you out.

Comment: @Lechucico please take a look at my updated answer. What this does is check how many times the for loop has iterated, and it opens a new <div class="row">, fills it with 3 columns, and then closes that div.

Comment: Take a look at the rendered HTML -- does it look right? Is the issue here with your CSS? What is a `div.row` and `div.col`?

Comment: This is a row and col: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ The first example that appears is what i want.

Comment: This is what I need https://imgur.com/a/Rph1n, and I don't know how to do it (each col has to be a diferent user): For example. List(1,2,3,4,5,6) has to display row1(1,2,3), row2(4,5,6)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168257/discussion-between-joseph-and-lechucico).